# Fresh debian install only able to connect to some websites

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I just installed the newest debian version and when trying to use the pre-installed browser (Firefox), I can only connect to some websites. Google, YouTube and Facebook for example work. Most sites however don't work.

I also noticed that the whole system seems to slow down from time to time. Like every few seconds everything will lag including mouse movements and videos that are being played.

Any help or requests for more information are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In which way the other sites "don't work"?

You get connection errors, they show nothing, they are too slow loading?

For system slowness, have you check resource usage with `top` command? What are your system specs?

Comment: They don't load at all. In Firefox it says server not found ("Hmm, we're having trouble finding that site."). When I ping a site that isn't loading it says "connect: Network is unreachable". I also tried installing Linux mint and now the lagging is gone but the network problem is the exact same.

Comment: Can you try MTR or curl to one of this domain, to see where the communication stops?
Also, have you tried checking if it's a DNS servers problem? 
Which are the DNS servers listed by `systemd-resolve --status`?